# Signup button text is invisible when logged out

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If I visit any SE site as an anonymous user and try to click either the `inbox` or `awards` button, I see this:

[image]

The text in the "Sign up" button is invisible.

I experienced this in Firefox and Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: It is a very dark blue on Chrome Windows 10. Looks like the styling for links to appear as button has some CSS rules missing, probably a __primary variant.

Answer (score 3):

This got fixed this afternoon. Thanks for pointing it out. Apologies for the delay, holiday code freezes got in our way. Hey, that rhymed!